# Remove phrase with apostrophe in R for word cloud

Tags: r, special-characters, tm, word-cloud

Thanks to the help of this community I've been able to make some word clouds from movie scripts and it's getting easier and easier. Someone requested I do the movie Pan, so I found the script and off I went.

The problem is there are a few words appearing that I have coded to remove. They look like 'il, 've, 're, etc. Note the leading apostrophe.

Here is my code:

```
text = readLines("C:/Users/MyName/Downloads/Pan.txt",encoding="UTF-8")

content2 = Corpus(VectorSource(text))
content2 = tm_map(content2, removeNumbers)
content2 = tm_map(content2, tolower)
content2 = tm_map(content2, removeWords, c("'il","'re","cont'd"))
content2 = tm_map(content2, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
content2 = tm_map(content2, removePunctuation)
content2 = tm_map(content2,PlainTextDocument)
wordcloud(content2, min.freq = 10, colors =  RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6,"Spectral"),max.words=150)
```

I've tried searching for 'il in Notepad++ with no luck and R's removeWords function doesn't seem to be taking care of it either. I know that apostrophes and other special characters can sometimes require special methods, but I'm stuck here. Any ideas?

Here is the script source if interested: http://pastebin.com/JiK3pF5f

Thank you! Here is what the word cloud currently looks like. If you have any styling comments too, I'm all ears.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? I've just added removal of whitespace and don't see e.g. `'il`

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
text = readLines("~/Downloads/JiK3pF5f.txt", warn = F)
content2 = Corpus(VectorSource(text))
content2 = tm_map(content2, removeNumbers)
content2 = tm_map(content2, tolower)
content2 = tm_map(content2, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
content2 = tm_map(content2, removePunctuation)
content2 = tm_map(content2, trimws)
content2 = tm_map(content2, PlainTextDocument)

wordcloud(content2, min.freq = 10, colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6,"Spectral"),max.words=150)
```

The result:

[image: wordcloud]

Comment: Unfortunately yes they are still there. I ran that exact code and here is what I see. Notice towards the bottom there is 're and 'il. Can you post a picture of your word cloud?

http://i.imgur.com/4lG6Gkx.png?1

Comment: It might be the encoding. I removed the portion of my readLines() with the UTF-8 option and I'm noticing some weird results. Also if I use the pastebin file like you did and run the code I noticed TM appearing when an apostrophe should.

Comment: Interesting, I've posted the image I'm getting. Can you find in the Corpus an example of an `'il`?

Comment: Thank you. I must admit I'm not sure how to search a corpus. It seems the grep() function can be used but this is a specific phrase. I've searched SOF and Google for tips but haven't found an example I can model yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried gsub to replace those characters? For example:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
text = readLines("~/Downloads/JiK3pF5f.txt", warn = F)

text=gsub("'re", '', text)

content2 = Corpus(VectorSource(text))
content2 = tm_map(content2, removeNumbers)
content2 = tm_map(content2, tolower)
content2 = tm_map(content2, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
content2 = tm_map(content2, removePunctuation)
content2 = tm_map(content2, trimws)
content2 = tm_map(content2, PlainTextDocument)

wordcloud(content2, min.freq = 10, colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6,"Spectral"),max.words=150)
```

Also you can try with Quanteda: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quanteda/vignettes/quickstart.html

It also has a bit better performance than tm

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The gsub method didn't work for me. I don't know why.